# how to check if link directs to an existing image javascript

Tags: javascript, image, exists

I want to know if a links redirects to an actual existing image in javascript because I don't want the following to happen:

```html
<img src="http://idontexist.lol/fakeimg.png" alt="non existant image" width="400">
```

Comment: use onload function for image to ensure if image exists

Comment: You can try hitting the URL and see if it's giving 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload()` function is used to detect if image is valid in url.If you enter onload function it is valid image url

```js
function test(event,val){
   console.log("image"+val+" is loaded");
   event.style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<img src="http://idontexist.lol/fakeimg.png"onload="test(this,1)" alt="non existant image"style="display:none" width="400">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27g"onload="test(this,2)"style="display:none" alt="non existant image" width="400">
```